# Typo3 extbase User Auth Service

Tags: service, authentication, typo3, extbase

I try to write a service module, that fetches userdata from a webservice. I found this [tutorial](http://www.marc-willmann.de/typo3-tutorials/anleitungen/frontend-user-login-gegen-eigene-datenquelle/),  but it shows the 'old' way of building extensions. Is it possible to write a extbase-extension like this? How it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Extbase` ("the new way") is about `MVC`, not about auth services, thus this tutorial is still valid.

Claus Due (an `Extbase` specialist) wrote an auth extension, maybe you want to study his code: https://github.com/NamelessCoder/google_auth

Comment: Was it this extension? https://github.com/NamelessCoder/google_auth I verified with archive.org and changed the link in the answer.